# Coordinating two `ButtonGroup`

Tags: java, swing, buttongroup

I have a group of 3 `JRadioButtonMenuItem` in a menu, and 3 `JToggleButton` in a toolbar. Each of them is bound to 3 `Action`, so that when I disable one action, both the corresponding item and button will be disabled.

When I click a menu item, I would expect also the corresponding toolbar button to get selected, but it seems that the "unclicked" group has its own strange way to react to these events (with a pattern that I didn't try to identify).

Here's the menu group code (simplified):

```
ButtonGroup menuGrp = new ButtonGroup();

JRadioButtonMenuItem itemA = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(actionA);
JRadioButtonMenuItem itemB = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(actionB);
JRadioButtonMenuItem itemC = new JRadioButtonMenuItem(actionC);

menuGrp.add(itemA);
menuGrp.add(itemB);
menuGrp.add(itemC);

itemA.setSelected(true);
```

and here toolbar group code:

```
ButtonGroup toolbarGrp = new ButtonGroup();

JToggleButton buttonA = new JToggleButton(actionA);
JToggleButton buttonB = new JToggleButton(actionB);
JToggleButton buttonC = new JToggleButton(actionC);

toolbarGrp.add(buttonA);
toolbarGrp.add(buttonB);
toolbarGrp.add(buttonB);

buttonA.setSelected(true);
```

Comment: You add buttonB to the toolbarGrp twice. It is just a typo or do you have it in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how exactly are you doing it, but this code is working for me:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButtonMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JToggleButton;


public class Button
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu menu = new JMenu("Foo");

        ButtonGroup menuGrp = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButtonMenuItem itemA = new JRadioButtonMenuItem();
        JRadioButtonMenuItem itemB = new JRadioButtonMenuItem();
        JRadioButtonMenuItem itemC = new JRadioButtonMenuItem();
        menuGrp.add(itemA);
        menuGrp.add(itemB);
        menuGrp.add(itemC);
        menu.add(itemA);
        menu.add(itemB);
        menu.add(itemC);
        itemA.setSelected(true);

        bar.add(menu);
        frame.setJMenuBar(bar);

        JPanel content = new JPanel();

        ButtonGroup toolbarGrp = new ButtonGroup();
        JToggleButton buttonA = new JToggleButton();
        JToggleButton buttonB = new JToggleButton();
        JToggleButton buttonC = new JToggleButton();
        toolbarGrp.add(buttonA);
        toolbarGrp.add(buttonB);
        toolbarGrp.add(buttonC);
        buttonA.setSelected(true);

        content.add(buttonA);
        content.add(buttonB);
        content.add(buttonC);

        itemA.setAction(new MyAction(buttonA));
        itemB.setAction(new MyAction(buttonB));
        itemC.setAction(new MyAction(buttonC));
        buttonA.setAction(new MyAction(itemA));
        buttonB.setAction(new MyAction(itemB));
        buttonC.setAction(new MyAction(itemC));
        frame.setContentPane(content);
        frame.setSize(300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    static class MyAction extends AbstractAction
    {
        AbstractButton button;

        public MyAction(AbstractButton button){
            this.button = button;
        }

        @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            button.setSelected(true);
        }   


    }
}
```

Comment: Actually I am sharing the action for each corresponding couple (itemA buttonA -> actionA, ...) As per [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Action.html#SELECTED_KEY), they should be sharing Action's state without selecting manually. I tried to modify your code to reflect mine and: enabled state is indeed shared (as in my code), but now one group just ignores the other's selection. And I can't understand why in my code this last thing works (although partially).

Comment: Anyway you put me on the right path. I finally solved by calling `putValue(Action.SELECTED_KEY, true)` in each `actionPerformed()`, which is like manually selecting the action instead of the components. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can link the state of any two (or more) buttons by sharing the button model among them, in this case:

```
itemA.setModel(buttonA.getModel());
itemB.setModel(buttonB.getModel());
itemC.setModel(buttonC.getModel());
```

That way you can avoid calling the `putValue(Action.SELECTED_KEY, true)`. Not sure whether that is actually an improvement, but I do like it more.

Answer (score 1):

For the record (years later), this is due to a change made in Java 6.  You can see [JDK-6397556](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6397556) for some discussion, but the short version is that because fully tying *stateful* buttons to Actions requires the button to push that state (selected vs unselected) back into the Action, they didn't want to break existing programs that didn't expect it.

So, if you're going to construct a toggle button from an Action, and you want the button's initial selected state to follow the Action's selected state, you have to opt-in by setting `Action.SELECTED_KEY` to a non-null Boolean value *prior* to creating the button:

```
Action action = .....;
action.putValue (Action.SELECTED_KEY, Boolean.TRUE);
JCheckBox checkbox = new JCheckBox(action);
```

Obviously, pass `Boolean.FALSE` to fully tie them together with an initial state of "not selected".  (If your code has already determined the initial selection state in some other boolean variable, then simply doing `Boolean.valueOf(initiallySelectedOrNot)` will work, or you can rely on autoboxing to DTRT.)